# Button click crashes my app when multiple EditTexts are empty

Tags: android, android-fragments

I made a discount app with 2 input and a button to calculate the result.

This discount app implements a fragment to achieve the tabview swipe

However the app crashes when pressed the button while 2 edittext or 1 edittext are empty.

I had use the toast to show up when editext is empty but it didnt work.

```
package com.ywapp.yw.discountcal;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    // Variable Declaration
    EditText price_box_field;
    EditText discount_box_field;
    TextView result_text_field;
    Button cal_btn;

    double price,discount,result,save;


    public Tab1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);


        final EditText price_box_field=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.price_box);
        final EditText discount_box_field=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.discount_price_box);

        final TextView result_text_field=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.result_text);
        Button cal_btn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.cal_btn);



        cal_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                price=Double.parseDouble(price_box_field.getText().toString());
                discount=Double.parseDouble(discount_box_field.getText().toString());

                if(price_box_field.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"please enter something in text box",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if(discount_box_field.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"please enter something in text box",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                result=(price-((price*discount)/100));
                save=price-result;

                String result_word="After Discount: RM ";
                String result_set=result_word+String.format("%.2f", result)+"\nYou saved RM "+String.format("%.2f", save);
                result_text_field.setText(result_set);


            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful for others to help if you could include you stack trace from logcat to your question

Comment: As riadrifai's answer might solve your question already, I just want to add, you might want to limit user to input anything except number to your EditTexts, or validate it too in your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the check before parsing the values:

```
cal_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(price_box_field.getText().length()==0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"please enter something in text box",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return; //to stop the method from parsing empty values
            }

            if(discount_box_field.getText().length()==0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"please enter something in text box",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return; //to stop the method from parsing empty values
            }


            price=Double.parseDouble(price_box_field.getText().toString());
            discount=Double.parseDouble(discount_box_field.getText().toString());




            result=(price-((price*discount)/100));
            save=price-result;

            String result_word="After Discount: RM ";
            String result_set=result_word+String.format("%.2f", result)+"\nYou saved RM "+String.format("%.2f", save);
            result_text_field.setText(result_set);


        }
    });
```